# Why does my Program not register that a socket could not have been created?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, server

I made a little Chess application and there is an offline mode in case you can't connect to the server. The client should try to connect, catch the UnknownHostException and then continue on. But ever since i forwarded my port in the router, the Exception isn't being registered anymore and the client just necks itself. It doesn't crash, it doesn't catch an Exception, even when sorrounding with try/catch, and it doesn't do anything anymore.

Here's the Java method:

```
public void startConnection(String adress, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println("try taking connection");
        clientSocket = new Socket(adress, port+1);
        System.out.println("uhh1");
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        System.out.println("uhh2");
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("uhh3");
    }
```

the sysout stops at "try taking connection", no errors, no server online. It does work when the server is online.

Is there a way for me to set a time-out, or any better solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: tag with the language please

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the wrong approach for offline work. What's happening here is the new Socket call fails and throws the UnknownHostException. It's difficult to continue like you want to do, because clientSocket is not initialized so getOutputStream() would fail as well. I'm not sure about your application's architecture, but you should identify opportunities to cache data locally and send the data to the server when the application is able to connect again.

Comment: The point is that you should be able to play singleplayer even if the server is shut down, but i can't click anything because the code literally stay at that second line "clientSocket = new Socket(adress, port+1);) " As i said, no exception caught, the program just stops continueing after trying to create the new Socket. The startConnection()-Method is only run once, as soon as the client starts, if it fails, the game just continues in offline mode. It's all implemented and works fine on local host. Just not with the port forwarded.